How to compare row values of multiple columns with the same header in different sheets, even if those columns are only in the same sheet?
Below is the code I have to compare the row values of the columns that have the same header 'abc', 'def', and 'ghi' in ws_checks, assuming those columns are in both Sheet1 and Sheet2. How can it be expanded to compare multiple columns (not just 2, can be any number of columns in 1 sheet or across all Sheets 1 to 5) that share the same column header?
'''
Dim r, lr, lr1, lr2, col1, col2, lc_checks, nextCol As Long
Dim Rng1, Rng2, Found1, Found2 As Range
Dim foundX As Boolean
Dim header, headerList As Variant

' List of column headers to compare 
headerList = Array("abc", "def", "ghi")

' Loop through each header in the list
For Each header In headerList
    ' Find the column index of the header in both sheets
    On Error Resume Next ' Handle the case where header might not be found
    col1 = Application.Match(header, ws1.Rows(2), 0)
    col2 = Application.Match(header, ws2.Rows(2), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0 
    
   ' Find the last row with data in the columns
    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, col1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Find the next column to paste the next check
    lc_checks = ws_checks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    nextCol = lc_checks + 1
    
    ' Compare values in the rows of the current column header
    For r = 3 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(lr1, lr2)
    
    ws_checks.Cells(1, nextCol).Value = ws1.Cells(2, col1).Value 
        
        If ws1.Cells(r, col1).Value = ws2.Cells(r, col2).Value Then
            ws_checks.Cells(r - 1, nextCol).Value = "Match"
        Else: ws_checks.Cells(r - 1, nextCol).Value = "Mismatch"
     
    Next r

'''

How do you propose to handle flagging "Match/Mismatch" when columns are being compared across multiple sheets, not just two sheets?

FYI Application.Match doesn't raise a run-time error if no match is found, but returns an error value instead, so col1 and/or col2 could end up as error values and crash the next lines of code....   Related maybe - you cannot Dim a comma-separated list of variables as specific types by adding the type on the last on in the list - every variable needs a type.

@TimWilliams The columns with same header are supposed to have same values in all of their rows, and my question is how to compare all those columns even if they appear in 1 sheet or 4 sheets..

Yes I understand that but if for example the same column exists on 4 sheets but has different values on those sheets how should it be flagged?  "Match" only if the same value is in the same row on each of the 4 sheets, otherwise "no match"   ?  Why ignore values at the end of one column if another column happens to be shorter?

@TimWilliams Right, it would be good to check they have the same length too. Do you have any suggestion to my question?

Yes, but you've not answered my question on how the flagging would work if there are multiple sheets with the same column name.  Is there only one "master" sheet to which the other sheets should be compared, or should each pair of sheets be compared. Or ?  You need to explain exactly what the code needs to do, because the exact process outlined in your posted code won't apply.

Try this out.  Comments in code.
Option Explicit

Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 2 'header row# on all sheets

Sub CompareColumns()
    Dim cols As Collection, headerList, header, n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rng As Range, v, v2, wb As Workbook, wsCheck As Worksheet
    Dim cPos As Long, ok As Boolean, colOK As Boolean, clr As Long, flag As String
    
    headerList = Array("abc", "def", "ghi") 'column headers to compare
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set wsCheck = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ws_checks")
    wsCheck.Cells.Clear
    
    For Each header In headerList             'check each header
        Debug.Print "---Checking:" & header & "---"
        Set cols = CompareRanges(wb, header)  'check all sheets for the header
        If cols.Count > 1 Then                'any sheets to compare?
            colOK = True                      'reset flag
            cPos = HeaderPos(wsCheck, header) 'header position on "check "sheet
            ResetFill cols                    'clear previous flags
            For i = 1 To cols(1).Cells.Count  'column length
                flag = ""                     'reset flag
                v = cols(1)(i)                'read value from first column
                For j = 2 To cols.Count       'check other columns
                    v2 = cols(j).Cells(i).Value
                    If Len(v) = 0 Or Len(v2) = 0 Then 'either value is blank?
                        clr = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                        flag = "---"
                    Else
                        If v2 <> v Then   'mismatch?
                            clr = vbRed
                            flag = "X"
                        End If
                    End If
                    If Len(flag) > 0 Then
                        For Each rng In cols  'flag all columns at this position
                            rng.Cells(i).Interior.Color = clr
                        Next rng
                        colOK = False         'column not matched
                        Exit For              'done checking
                    End If
                Next j 'next comparison column
                'flag the cell on ws_checks
                wsCheck.Cells(cols(1)(i).Row, cPos).Value = IIf(Len(flag) = 0, "O", flag)
            Next i
            wsCheck.Cells(HEADER_ROW, cPos).Interior.Color = IIf(colOK, vbGreen, vbRed)
        End If
    Next header
End Sub

'Check all sheets in workbook `wb` for the header `hdr` on the configured row
'  Return a collection of all data columns below found headers, sized to the max length
'   of all of the returned ranges
Function CompareRanges(wb As Workbook, hdr) As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet, col As New Collection, maxRow As Long, lr As Long
    Dim rng As Range, m, i As Long, c As Range, lc As Long
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        lc = ws.Cells(HEADER_ROW, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For Each c In ws.Cells(HEADER_ROW, 1).Resize(1, lc).Cells
            If c.Value = hdr Then
                col.Add ws.Cells(HEADER_ROW + 1, c.Column)
                lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                If lr > maxRow Then maxRow = lr
            End If
        Next c
    Next ws
    Set CompareRanges = New Collection
    If col.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    For Each rng In col  'make all columns same size as the longest one
        CompareRanges.Add rng.Resize(maxRow - HEADER_ROW)
    Next rng
End Function

'Clear any fill from a collection of ranges
Sub ResetFill(col As Collection)
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In col
        Debug.Print rng.Parent.Name, rng.Address
        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Next rng
End Sub

'Return the column number for header `hdr` on sheet `ws`
'  Add the header if not found
Function HeaderPos(ws As Worksheet, hdr) As Long
    Dim m
    m = Application.Match(hdr, ws.Rows(HEADER_ROW), 0)
    If IsError(m) Then
        m = ws.Cells(HEADER_ROW, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Len(ws.Cells(HEADER_ROW, m)) > 0 Then m = m + 1
        ws.Cells(HEADER_ROW, m).Value = hdr
    End If
    HeaderPos = CLng(m)
End Function


Thank you so much for taking your time for the code above. I think I get your original question now.. there's a sheet (ws_checks) to paste those column headers and if the values of all columns with header 'abc' match on row 7, the ws_checks with header 'abc' will have 'O' on row 7, if any value of those columns doesn't match on row 15, 'X' appears in row 15 of ws_checks. And the header 'abc' in ws_checks is green or red depending on if all row values match.

See edits above

Hi Tim, can you point me to how to paste the checks starting with Row 1 instead?

You can just delete row 1 from ws_checks when done.

Thank you, that worked. Now, I'm having another problem: if I delete the column with header 'abc' in Sheet1 so that it appears twice in Sheet2 only, your code doesn't add 'abc' in Check worksheet. Also, if there're 3 columns with header 'abc' in workbook and there's a mismatch in a row, only the cells of the first 2 columns are colored red.

Maybe it's a problem in Excel; the ResetFill doesn't seem to work.

Your question has nothing about the column being repeated in the same sheet, so no my code doesn't handle that.  You can try modifying CompareRanges to detect the header if it occurs more than once.  I don't know what the issue with ResetFill is - what exactly does that look like?

Well, I did ask for 'any number of columns in 1 sheet' in my original question. ResetFill just worked, I'm not sure what was wrong.

Ok fair enough - see edits to CompareRanges above.  Should now capture >1 instance of any column per sheet.

Hi Tim, sorry to bother you. Can you help with adding 1 more condition? Color the compared cells grey if any of them is empty, and display the status as '---'? Thank you.

See updated code above - that should cover flagging blanks
